# Maximal Lyapunov Exponent

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, dynamical-systems

I am trying to figure out the equation below so that I can re-create it and use it for probability of dynamic systems in MATLAB.

[image]

I am trying to figure out what the [image] symbol stands for and how to use it with MATLAB.

If anyone can give me walkthrough of this equation with some test data, that would be more than appreciated.

Comment: Where, exactly, did you encounter this expression?

Comment: This expression is used for prediction in dynamical systems. This above expression was found on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponent

Comment: "the rate of separation of infinitesimally close trajectories" is the key phrase; in practical work, your trajectories ought to be separated by an amount that is some small multiple of machine epsilon...

Comment: @Kyle: δ refers to a difference.

Comment: Most of the time, it is possible to linearize the system around $Z_0$ (sometimes even analytically). Then the Lyapunov exponent is the eigenvalue of the Jacobian at $Z_0$ with the maximal real part.

Comment: @Fabian: A difference of what? What exactly should Z be? It appears that you can plug in a t?

Comment: You didn't still tell us how your dynamical system is defined. Typically, one would think about an ordinary differential equation (with respect to $t$). $Z(t)$ then defines the "coordinates" of the system at time $t$ and $Z_0$ at time $t=0$.

Comment: I don't know definition of my dynamical system. I am programming this in MATLAB so that any timeseries that is sent can be calculated against.

Comment: For the Lyapunov exponent you need the **difference** between two time series which are (initially) sufficiently close together.